# Xamarin Forms : How to write a Service which will run continuously in background till the app is uninstalled from the device?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to implement background service in Xamarin. Forms which is kept running in the device until the app is installed on the device.
I want to send the user's current location to the server at every 5 seconds even if the app is in the stack or removed from the stack.

I need to send the user's location to the server using this service and keep the signalR connection alive in the background

Comment: In android, you cannot keep the background service awlays running and you want to send current location at 5 secounds, the best way to achieve a forground service.There is simialr case：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55752147/how-to-create-service-doing-work-at-period-time-in-xamarin-forms/55757316#55757316

Comment: And in iOS an app can't _typically_ run in background except in some situations and categories one of them being **[Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/registering-applications-to-run-in-background)** category. Take a look at this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-walkthroughs/location-walkthrough).

Answer (score 0):

A bound service is an exception to the rule introduced in Oreo. An app can still run in the background when your app is backgrounded. I didn't require any changes in my app when I first supported Oreo and Pie is the same. You should probably look at starting your bound service by creating your own Application class and starting your bound service in its OnCreate.