# Keep task working when the app is in the background

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, background-process

I'm coding a map tracking app on Xamarin forms. I'm using `async tasks(with Device.StartTimer)` to keep track of the location and another task for counter timer, but when I need to open another app, like a music app or whatever the app can't keep track while it is in the background. All tasks are stopping when I send the app in the background. When I start the app again, the tasks are not continued.
I just need to keep working while app running.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You should use background task in this case, which is running outside the life cycle of the application. You can find more information here [Xamarin background tasks](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-background-tasks/)

Answer (score 1):

Due to [Background Execution Limits in Android 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/#background-execution-limits-in-android-80) or later, Normal service will be killed when in the Background.

In the Android 8.0 or later, I suggest you to achieve a [foreground service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services) to achieve that( receive higher priority than a "regular" service and a foreground service must provide a Notification that Android will display as long as the service is running).

You can use dependence service to open a foreground service in xamarin forms.

**IService.cs** create a interface for android to start service.

```
public interface IService
{
  void Start();
}
```

Then achieved `DependentService` to start a Foreground Service.

**DependentService.cs**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(DependentService))]
namespace TabGuesture.Droid
{
  [Service]
public class DependentService : Service, IService
{
public void Start()
{
    var intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, 
    typeof(DependentService));


    if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        Android.App.Application.Context.StartForegroundService(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        Android.App.Application.Context.StartService(intent);
    }
}

public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}
public const int SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID = 10000;
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, 
StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
{
    // From shared code or in your PCL

    CreateNotificationChannel();
    string messageBody = "service starting";

    var notification = new Notification.Builder(this, "10111")
    .SetContentTitle(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.app_name))
    .SetContentText(messageBody)
    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.main)
    .SetOngoing(true)
    .Build();
    StartForeground(SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    //do you work
    return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
}


void CreateNotificationChannel()
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
        // support library). There is no need to create a notification
        // channel on older versions of Android.
        return;
    }

    var channelName = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.channel_name);
    var channelDescription = GetString(Resource.String.channel_description);
    var channel = new NotificationChannel("10111", channelName, NotificationImportance.Default)
    {
        Description = channelDescription
    };

    var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
    notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
 }
}
}
```

Here is a similar thread about your needs.
[How to create service doing work at period time in Xamarin.Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55752147/how-to-create-service-doing-work-at-period-time-in-xamarin-forms/55757316#55757316)

For IOS background Tasks. you can refer to [this thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/)

Comment: Thank you, i will check.