# How do asynchronous Tasks in Xamarin.Forms work with iOS/Android background modes

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I've read the Microsoft Docs about backgrounding on mobile and have seen the various lifecycle states the app can be in. But I'm still a bit confused about the idea of a background Task in C# and the idea of *backgrounding* in iOS/Android.

**Question**:
Let's say I start a new background C# Task, in a ViewModel or Model class (exact pattern irrelevant). It receives data via a WebSocket as well as makes HTTP requests, and keeps running indefinitely. Does this task continue to run when the app is moved to the background by the user? If not, why, and what would I need to do to ensure it keeps running?

Comment: In the Android part, you can use dependence service to open a foregroud service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services You can run your Https requests in the foreground service, it will push a notification and keep the service alive when the application is moved to the background by user.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Thanks for that, and an excellent article. Expect nothing less from Microsoft docs. So if I dont register it as a foreground service in Android, a regular Task that I spawn somewhere in my code that runs on a background thread, will get stopped automatically when the app is backgrounded?

Comment: If you do not use foreground service, it will be stopped automatically by GC in Android 
 when your application in the background. Because your application do not have any visuable control to keep the application alive. Before Android 8.0, we can use normal `Service` to keep the background task running. But In Android 8.0 or later, Android have background execution limits, service will be killed in serveral minutes when Application in the background. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/#background-execution-limits-in-android-80

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Thanks, that makes sense. If you’re able to identify iOS requirements as well then I’d be happy to accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Android part, you can use dependence service to open a foregroud service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

You can run your Https requests in the foreground service, it will push a notification and keep the service alive when the application is moved to the background by user.

Here is my answer about use foreground service, you can refer to it as well.
[How to running method webservice in background from android xamarin form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60500768/how-to-running-method-webservice-in-background-from-android-xamarin-form/60520038#60520038)

In the IOS part, I suggest you achieve it with Backgrounding with Tasks.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/ios-backgrounding-with-tasks

You can put your background HTTP request to `BeginBackgroundTask` method like following format code.

```
nint taskID = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask( () => {

// your  background HTTP request
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The wording in this section is confusing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/ios-backgrounding-with-tasks#creating-background-safe-tasks. “When the task is complete, we call EndBackgroundTask and pass in the same identifier. This is important because iOS will terminate the application if a BeginBackgroundTask does not have a matching EndBackgroundTask”. But I don’t know when my task will end. By definition, it’s a long-running task. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Can you please share a link to the documentation that states that a background task can run for an infinite amount of time while the app is in the background? I’ve only seen docos that mention the 10 minute limit.

Comment: In IOS, there are serveral applications are allowed long-running tasks constantly, such as Audio , VoIP  External Accessories and Bluetooth Newsstand .. etc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/registering-applications-to-run-in-background But I do not recommand you to pretend to be these apps(If your application do not have these function), because App Store do not allowed you to do that.

Comment: Yea, I noticed those categories, however my requirement does not fit in any of them, leaving me in a tough spot.

Comment: I consulted my colleagues, now there is no good way to implement it in IOS part.